# Scroll elements to left and show rightmost element

Tags: html, css

I have a unordered list, inside a container, I want to set the CSS such that when new li is added the last li is show and the left most li is hidden if there is no space in the container

li1 > li2

when li4 is added it should look like

> li2 > li3

basicially I want to show last 2 li's

https://jsfiddle.net/5snmggtg/1/

in this fiddle result should be 2 3 ( it is "1 2" now)

**HTML**

`<span>
  <ul >
  <li>1</li> > 
  <li>2</li> >
  <li>3</li>
  </ul>
</span>`

**CSS**

```
li {
   display: inline;
 }

ul{
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 15px 
 }
```

Comment: i don't think this can be done with CSS , you can hide the `li:first-child{display:none}` but if you add `<li>5</li>` you should hide the second child , then the 3rd and so on. this is jQuery territory. 

and i think there's a problem in your logic. you want to have always 3 li shown, or 2 ? you must decide . when you have li1,li2,li3 , you want to hide li1 ......... when you have li1,li2,li3,li4 you should hide li1,li2 . right ?

Comment: added an answer with 2 solutions. 1 with CSS ( i was wrong, you can do this with CSS ) and 1 with JQ . you choose :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two solutions

**A. with CSS**

```css
li {
   display: inline;
 }

ul{
  position: absolute;
 
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 15px ;
  padding:0;
 }

 li:not(:last-child):not(:nth-last-child(2)) {display:none}
```

```html
<span>
  <ul >
  <li>1 > </li> 
  <li>2  ></li>
  <li>3  ></li> 
  <li>4 ></li> 
   <li>5 </li> 
  </ul>
</span>
```

**B. with jQ** below you hide all the previous elements of the `li:last-child` except the immediate previous element :)

let me know if this is what you want

see snippet below

```js
var item = $("ul li:last-child")
var sib = $(item).prev()
$(item).prevAll().not(sib).hide()
```

```css
li {
   display: inline;
 }

ul{
  position: absolute;
 
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 15px ;
  padding:0;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <ul >
  <li>1 > </li> 
  <li>2  ></li>
  <li>3  ></li> 
  <li>4 ></li> 
   <li>5 </li> 
  </ul>
</span>
```